# Calculating the time at which a person is working most efficiently from a given equation

Tags: calculus

Please help me to solve this.

> An average worker who comes to work at $8$AM will have produced $$Q(t) = -t^3 + 9t^2 + 12t$$ units $t$ hours later.
>
> At what time during the morning is the worker performing most efficiently?

Comment: Welcome to StackExchange. What work have you already done on the question? This will help people guage how much you know and what to include in their answers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We are told that $$Q(t)=−t^3+9t^2+12t$$

The worker is working most efficiently when this graph reaches its maxima

To find the maximum point of this graph, we first need to calculate the derivative

$$Q'(t)=-3t^2+18t+12$$

Any 'turning points' of the graph will occur when the derivative is equal to zero, i.e. $Q'(t)=0$

\begin{align}-3t^2+18t+12&=0\\
3t^2-18t-12&=0\\
t^2-6t-4&=0\\
\left(t-3\right)^2-9-4&=0\tag{completing the square}\\
\left(t-3\right)^2-13&=0\\
\left(t-3\right)^2&=13\\
t-3&=\pm\sqrt{13}\\
t&=3\pm\sqrt{13}\end{align}

We can see that $t=3-\sqrt{13}<0$ and so we must have $t=3+\sqrt{13}$

> Note: We can check that this is the maxima in one of two ways:
>
> - [Sketch the graph](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%E2%88%92t%5E3%2B9t%5E2%2B12t) (here I used WolframAlpha but you should be able to do it by hand)
> - Calculate the second derivative at each point, $Q''(t)=-6t+18$, the maxima occurs when this second derivative is negative

Therefore the worker is working most productively $3+\sqrt{13}\approx6.61$ hours after $8$AM, which is approximately $2:37$PM ($0.61\times 1\text{ hour}\approx37\text{ minutes}$)

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**. One may find local maxima and local minima of a polynomial at points where the derivative vanishes, thus evaluate
$$
Q'(t) =\left( -t^3 + 9t^2 + 12t\right)'
$$ then find all values such that
$$
Q'(t)=0.
$$